# plotting multiple graphs in shiny using multidimension dataframe : unable to plot

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to use shiny to plot multiple graphs of lines and bars using a multidimensional dataframe. i run my code and i come up with error message: *Warning: Error in as.character: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
Stack trace (innermost first):
    4: 
    3: do.call
    2: print.shiny.appobj
    1: 
Error in as.character(x) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'*

I have tried everything. The plots do not appear at all.

This is my code: Please help me take a look on what is wrong. Thanks!

```
require(rCharts)
options(RCHART_LIB = 'polycharts')
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Percentage in wage and employmnent"),

  sidebarPanel(
    "Funding",
    selectInput(inputId = "scn", 
                label = h3("Choose Funding Scenario"),
                choices = list("base" = 1, "fd" = 2,
                  "fdtx" = 3, names(dmb), selected = 1)),
    selectInput(inputId = "variable", 
                label = h3("Choose impact variable"),
                choices = list("n.tot" = 1,"gdp" = 2,"gini" = 3,"mdg1" = 4,"mdg2" = 5, "mdg4" = 6,
                               "mdg5" = 7,"mdgsanit7" = 8, "mdgwater7" = 9, names(dmb), selected = 1)),

      ),

  mainPanel(
    showOutput("chart1", "polycharts"),
    showOutput("chart2", "polycharts")
  )
))

require(rCharts)
options(RCHART_WIDTH = 800)
palette(c("#E41A1C", "#377EB8", "#4DAF4A", "#984EA3",
          "#FF7F00", "#FFFF33", "#A65628", "#F781BF", "#999999"))
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  selectedData <- reactive({dmb[, c(input$scn, input$variable)]
                           })
  output$chart1 <- renderChart({
    scn = input$scn
    emp <- subset(dmb[ dmb[,"measure"]=="wag.emp" & dmb[,"ind"]=="pcn" & dmb[,"scn"]=="base" & dmb[,"variable"]!="n.tot" , ] )
    wag <- subset(dmb, measure == "wag" & ind == "pcn" & scn == "scn" )
       p1 <- rPlot(x = list(var = "variable", sort = "value"), y = "value", 
                color = 'emp', data = emp, type = 'bar')
    p1$layer(x = "variable", y = "value", color = 'wag', 
             data = wag, type = 'bar', size = list(const = 3))



    return(p1)
  })
  output$chart2 <- renderChart({
    var = input$var
    variable = subset(dmb, variable == var)
    p2 <- rPlot(value ~ year, color = 'ind', type = 'line', data = variable)
    p2$guides(y = list(min = 0, title = ""))
    p2$guides(y = list(title = ""))
    p2$addParams(height = 300, dom = 'chart2')
    return(p2)
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[This is a snapshot of my dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pmUw.png)